# Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/Tags/1/Value: expected minLength: 1, actual: 0)"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to create a simple **step functions** in **serverless.yml**
Code is as below in serverless

```
    #Lambda definition
    test:
    name: ${self:service.name}-${self:provider.stage}-test
    handler: stepfunction/test.handler
    description: ${self:custom.gitVersion}
    timeout: 2
    package:
      include:
        - stepfunction/test.js
        - shared/logMetrics.js
        - newrelic-lambda-wrapper.js
        - shared/jwt-validate.js

    stepFunctions:
      stateMachines:
        recording:
          type: EXPRESS
          name: recording
          definition:
            Comment: "Recording file processing state machine"
            StartAt: hello_world
            States:
              hello_world:
                Type: Task
                Resource: 
                  Fn::GetAtt: [test,Arn]
                End: true
```

When I try to deploy this it results in the following error

```
>   ServerlessError: An error occurred: Recording - Resource handler
> returned message: "Model validation failed (#/Tags/1/Value: expected
> minLength: 1, actual: 0)" (RequestToken:
> a42d7e8d-7e45-a94f-6ace-0360ea737ec8, HandlerErrorCode:
> InvalidRequest).
>       at provider.request.then (C:\Code\microservices\aa-recording\aa-recording-api\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\lib\monitorStack.js:143:23)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   From previous event:
>       at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>       at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
>       at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)   From previous event:
>       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nouman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:50:4)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>       at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nouman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js:47:1)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this error has nothing to do with the **step functions** definiton, which is fine.
In serverless I've defined the tags also for versioning like below

```
tags:
    NewRelicIntegration: ${self:custom.enableNewRelic}
    Version: ${self:custom.gitVersion}
 custom:
    environmentType: ${opt:environmentType, "dev"}
    gitVersion: ${opt:gitVersion, ""}
```

Value of **gitVersion** is empty and for step functions CloudFormation tries to apply it (which is not the case with other resources like lambda's)

So we need to explicity set a default value like below for gitVersion to make it work.

```
     tags:
        NewRelicIntegration: ${self:custom.enableNewRelic}
        Version: ${self:custom.gitVersion}
     custom:
        environmentType: ${opt:environmentType, "dev"}
        gitVersion: ${opt:gitVersion, "null"}
```